# Why does this command get the @@Identity after an insert statement has been executed?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-ce

Just trying to perform an insert and then get the @@Identity but its proving a little difficult.

So I have the following Sql:

```
    int retInt = 0;

    string Sql = insertSql;

    Connection.Open();

    commandArg.CommandText = insertSql;

    commandArg.Connection = Connection;

    commandArg.ExecuteNonQuery();

    commandArg.CommandText = "SELECT @@Identity;";

    commandArg.CommandText = Sql;

    retInt = (int)commandArg.ExecuteScalar();

    return retInt;
```

But when I get to the ExecuteScalar command at the end I get a null reference exception.Am I doing something wrong with the csharp? Because when I do this on a Sql editor it works (when I execute both commands in line).

Hope someone can help....

(btw commandArg is passed in as a parameter)

UPDATE:

my original post was not right but I have changed and am still getting the error. Hope someone can help!

UPDATE 2:

After reading the below I can see my code is just plain sloppy so I fixed the code to be this and it works!...

```
SqlCeConnection myConnection = new SqlCeConnection(@"Data Source=C:\database.sdf");
            SqlCeCommand myCommand = new SqlCeCommand();
            myCommand.Connection = myConnection;

            myConnection.Open();

            myCommand.CommandText = "Insert into tbl_media (dateadded) values (getdate())";
            SqlCeDataReader insertReader =  myCommand.ExecuteReader();

            myCommand.CommandText = "select @@identity";
            SqlCeDataReader identityReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();

            myConnection.Close();
```

Comment: So you're overwriting your insert statement with the identity select statement?

Comment: In addition to what campbell said, you are overwriting your select statement with an insert statement. So effectively you are selecting when you should be inserting, and inserting when you should be selecting.

Comment: As an aside, it's better to use [SCOPE_IDENTITY()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx) instead of @@Identity. A table with a trigger that also inserts an identity value would return the wrong result with @@Identity (i.e., the value generated by the trigger's insert rather than the value generated by your insert).

Comment: sorry guys thats not the problem I just copied and pasted the incorrect sql Ive updated the answer now. Do you know why im still getting null reference exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use @@identity all the time in a separate query.  All that matters is that it is on the same connection.  As pointed out before you are NOT executing  "SELECT @@Identity;".   You set the value to commandArg.CommandText = Sql; before you ExecuteScalar.   Use retInt =   commandArg.ExecuteNonQuery(); and see if retInt = 1.  Put this in a try catch finally block to you can read the exception message.  It makes sense you are getting a null on the last line as the insert is not a Scalar command.

Comment: Hi Balam, yes your right im stupid! Okay I actually decided to do some reading up and draw some pictures about how SqlCommand and SqlConnections work and it makes a bit more sense I drew some pictures. I realise that you pass a connection to a command and then execute the command oncee you open the connection. I fixed the code and it works I will update my answer...

Comment: Whoever down voted two of the answers please consider removing your down vote.  They were just trying to help.  The criteria for a down vote is egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post, or an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect, vote it down. I posted because of one of the down vote answers. Yes it was not correct but it led to the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're trying to get the identity column for the item recently inserted.

Given that :

- SQL CE willonly let you execute one statement per command
- IDENTITY is out of scope
- you can't use stored procs

You could execute your insert, and then query for the last record that fits your inserted record:

```
 SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM MyTable
  WHERE Name = @CustomerName
 /* AND all your other matching criteria for the entity from your INSERT */
 ORDER BY CreateDate DESC
```

Answer (score -1):

Put your SELECT @@IDENTITY text at the end of your insertSql string. @@IDENTITY only works directly after an insert. It can't be in a different query.

Comment: you can only perform one SQL server ce command at a time so this wont work :-(